# Trying to upload specific characters in Python 3 using Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, python

I'm running this code in Windows Powershell and it includes this file called `languages.txt` where I'm trying to convert between bytes to strings:

Here is `languages.txt`:

```
Afrikaans
አማርኛ
Аҧсшәа
العربية
Aragonés
Arpetan
Azərbaycanca
Bamanankan
বাংলা
Bân-lâm-gú
Беларуская
Български
Boarisch
Bosanski
Буряад
Català
Чӑвашла
Čeština
Cymraeg
Dansk
Deutsch
Eesti
Ελληνικά
Español
Esperanto
فارسی
Français
Frysk
Gaelg
Gàidhlig
Galego
한국어
Հայերեն
हिन्दी
Hrvatski
Ido
Interlingua
Italiano
עברית
ಕನ್ನಡ
Kapampangan
ქართული
Қазақша
Kreyòl ayisyen
Latgaļu
Latina
Latviešu
Lëtzebuergesch
Lietuvių
Magyar
Македонски
Malti
मराठी
მარგალური
مازِرونی
Bahasa Melayu
Монгол
Nederlands
नेपाल भाषा
日本語
Norsk bokmål
Nouormand
Occitan
Oʻzbekcha/ўзбекча
ਪੰਜਾਬੀ
پنجابی
پښتو
Plattdüütsch
Polski
Português
Română
Romani
Русский
Seeltersk
Shqip
Simple English
Slovenčina
کوردیی ناوەندی
Српски / srpski
Suomi
Svenska
Tagalog
தமிழ்
ภาษาไทย
Taqbaylit
Татарча/tatarça
తెలుగు
Тоҷикӣ
Türkçe
Українська
اردو
Tiếng Việt
Võro
文言
吴语
ייִדיש
中文
```

Then, here is the code I used:

```
import sys
script, input_encoding, error = sys.argv


def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()

    if line:
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)


def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)

    print(raw_bytes, "<===>", cooked_string)


languages = open("languages.txt", encoding="utf-8")

main(languages, input_encoding, error)
```

Here's the output (credit: Learn Python 3 the Hard Way by Zed A. Shaw):

[image: Output 1]

[image: Output 2]

I don't know why it doesn't upload the characters and shows question blocks instead. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yes. `languages.txt` is encoded as a UTF-8 file.

Comment: It seems that the powershell is unable to print the characters. Perhaps it uses a font which does not support them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first string which fails is `አማርኛ`. The first character, `አ` is in unicode `12A0` (see [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+12A0)). In UTF-8, that is `b'\xe1\x8a\xa0'`. So, that part is obviously fine. The file really is UTF-8.

Printing did not raise an exception, so your output encoding can handle all of the characters. Everything is fine.

The only remaining reason I see for it to fail is that the font used in the console does not support all of the characters.

If it is just for play, you should not worry about it. Consider it working correctly.

---

On the other hand, I would suggest changing some things in your code:

1. You are running `main` recursively for each line. There is absolutely no need for that and it would run into recursion depth limit on a longer file. User a `for` loop instead.

```
for line in lines:
    print_line(line, encoding, errors)
```

2. You are opening the file as UTF-8, so reading from it automatically decodes UTF-8 into Unicode, then you encode it back into `row_bytes` and then encode again into `cooked_string`, which is the same as `line`. It would be a better exercise to read the file as raw binary, split it on newlines and then decode. Then you'd have a clearer picture of what is going on.

```
with open("languages.txt", 'rb') as f:
    raw_file_contents = f.read()
```